# What is the meaning of this sentence in <Why Functional Programming Matters>?

Tags: functional-programming

I'm a non English native speaker. While I'm reading [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://worrydream.com/refs/Hughes-WhyFunctionalProgrammingMatters.pdf), I get a little confused with the following paragraph:

> Even a functional programmer should be dissatisfied with these
>   so-called advantages, because they give no help in exploiting the
>   power of functional languages. One cannot write a program that is
>   particularly lacking in assignment statements, or particularly
>   referentially transparent. **There is no yardstick of program quality
>   here, and therefore no ideal to aim at.**

I'm not sure whether the last sentence means "deliberately writing no assignment statements does not improve a program's quality and therefore one should not do it" or just "there is no general yardstick of program quality".

Sorry if I asked in the wrong place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yeah, you probably should've asked it at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. What the author is saying is, if anyway there's no assignments at all, you can't then make your program better by omitting *more* of them. So *how* do you make your program better? The lack of assignments can't be *it*. What *positive* advantages does FP give you, as a programmer? Just saying there's no assignments doesn't help us understand the power that FP gives us. And to explain *what* that is, is the goal of the author in that article. That's how I read it anyway.

Comment: so, replace "so-called advantages" with "explanations", and it should become clearer.

Comment: @WillNess Yeah I agree with you on the explanation of the first two sentences. The third (bold) sentence, although trivial, is what I am actually wondering, since the two candidate explanation I gave above sounds completely different in my language and one of them must be misleading. Could you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: there are no assignments, so (amount of assignments in a program) is not a tool (yardstick) to measure the program's quality ("goodness") by. There *is* no such tool, in those terms. So, it's not *general*.

Comment: so you could state this as "deliberately writing no assignment statements is *not* the method of the problem solving which is FP".

Comment: so the word "here" (from "there is no yardstick of program quality **here**") means "in those terms" rather than "generally speaking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about language, not programming in particular. It might fit better at [english.SE].

Answer (score 0):

By a "yardstick of program quality", he means something you can measure or you can at least qualitatively look at to see if you're doing a good job or a bad one.  So attributes like speed, clarity of code, parallelizability, ease of making changes, ease of re-factoring, etc. are all either quantitative attributes you can measure or qualitative attributes where you can see that a new version of your program is better or worse than the old version.  You can give yourself, as a programmer, a job like "double the speed of this program" or "make it easier to add features to this program".  On the other hand:

> One cannot write a program that is particularly lacking in assignment statements, or particularly referentially transparent.

These things are *binary* (despite what ML programmers will tell you).  You cannot give yourself an assignment like "make this program use fewer assignment statements" (according to Hughes) or "make this program more referentially transparent".  That also makes it hard to tell if you've done a good job writing your program in the first place, or if you still have room for improvement.